# How to set background for the current prayer in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, background

I am making a widget for an app that display time and name of the daily prayers

so I have this function:

```
private fun updateBigWidget(){

    val view = RemoteViews(con.getPackageName(), R.layout.big_widget)
    val viewMedium = RemoteViews(con.getPackageName(), R.layout.medium_widget)

    
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL1, todayPrayers[0].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL1, todayPrayers[0].time)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL2, todayPrayers[1].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL2, todayPrayers[1].time)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL3, todayPrayers[2].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL3, todayPrayers[2].time)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL4, todayPrayers[3].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL4, todayPrayers[3].time)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL5, todayPrayers[4].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL5, todayPrayers[4].time)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerNameL6, todayPrayers[5].name)
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTimeL6, todayPrayers[5].time)

    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvState, settings.State)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvCurrentDate, _date)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvCurrentDateInHijriLL, islamic)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime1, todayPrayers[0].time)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime2, todayPrayers[1].time)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime3, todayPrayers[2].time)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime4, todayPrayers[3].time)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime5, todayPrayers[4].time)
    viewMedium.setTextViewText(R.id.tvPrayerTime6, todayPrayers[5].time)

    val theWidget = ComponentName(con, BigWidget::class.java)
    val theMediumWidget = ComponentName(con, MediumWidget::class.java)
    val manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(con)
    manager.updateAppWidget(theWidget, view)
    manager.updateAppWidget(theMediumWidget, viewMedium)
}
```

and this is its layout:

```
<LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="@drawable/last_widget"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvPrayerNameL1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:text="Fajer"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvPrayerTimeL1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:text="5:50Am"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout

            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvPrayerNameL2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:text="Fajer"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tvPrayerTimeL2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:text="5:50Am"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to highlight the current prayer with background from the project

I tried to use if condition for this but I couldn't do it

what is the best way to achieve this?

is it possible to do it? is there any library to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Also I'm not sure what you want a library for, setting a background is already possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can call LocalDateTime.now() to get the current time of the user and store it in a var. Based on this you can set if statements to see if the time is greater than or equal to the times you want to set. If the return call for the statement is true, then you can use (nameOfTheObjectYouWantToChange).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nameOfDrawable) to set the background of your object to the drawable of your choosing.

Comment: i tried to do the same but i couldn't call (nameOfTheObjectYouWantToChange) that i have

Comment: @Enigma Try using a findViewById to find the view and then attempt to call.